It takes a very, very long time before grub loads
I bought a new DELL laptop
DELL Precision M 3490 14 inch FHD Core Ultra 7 155H 16GB Intel Iris Xe
and installed Ubuntu 24.04 with a fully encrypted disk (LUKS)
after installation I turn off the laptop,
and reboot.
what I see:
after ~4 minutes I see GDM 0_o
im afraid -)
systemd-analyze critical chain: returned
graphical.target @2min 3.294s
└─multi-user.target @2min 3.294s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 33.324s +29.969s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 33.313s +8ms
      └─network.target @1min 33.296s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 32.308s +987ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 32.223s +84ms
            └─basic.target @1min 32.189s
              └─sockets.target @1min 32.189s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 32.179s +9ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 32.176s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @1min 33.465s +1.306s
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @1min 31.813s
                        └─system.slice @1min 599ms
                          └─-.slice @1min 599ms

systemd-analyze blame
30.266s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2dubuntu\x2d\x2dlv.device
30.079s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
29.969s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.145s gpu-manager.service
 7.263s apt-daily-upgrade.service
 5.725s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.169s fwupd.service
 1.306s systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
 1.220s fwupd-refresh.service
 1.025s systemd-journal-flush.service

what could be the problem? all services take a VERY long time to load

You seem to be reporting two separate things: i) a long time before grub loads and ii) a long time after grub loads until the operating system loads. Is that correct? Or is it only slow after grub?

Did it install the NPU driver? https://www.phoronix.com/news/Intel-NPU-Linux-Driver-1.2  That is something very new.
